# jQuery target parent of hidden element on hover (or not)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parent, jquery-hover

I'm trying to add a class (or CSS) to an `a`, the parent of a hidden `ul`, which shows up when the grand-parent `li` is hovered.
I can't change the code directly to get the result, so I need jQuery.
The code goes like this:

### HTML

```
<nav class="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
```

### CSS

```
.main-menu .sub-menu {display: none;}
.main-menu li:hover .sub-menu {display: block;}
.hovered {color: red;}
```

And here is what I'm trying with jQuery, but it doesn't work:

### jQuery

```
jQuery(".nm-main-menu ul.sub-menu).hover(function(){
  jQuery(this).parent().addClass("hovered");
});
```

Here it is all in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/somepaulo/gyowv1dx/).
Maybe `.hover()` is not the way to go...
Please help.

Comment: you have a missing quote `jQuery(".nm-main-menu ul.sub-menu)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(".nm-main-menu ul.sub-menu").hover(function(){
  jQuery(this).parent().addClass("hovered");
});
```

You missed a double quote inside the selector. It's working.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gyowv1dx/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a double quote at the end in jquery selector. Also you can access jquery by just using $.
Here is the modified fiddle

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyowv1dx/4/)

`$(".main-menu ul.sub-menu").hover(function(){
 $(this).parent().addClass("hovered");
 });`

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use jQuery for this one.

Comment: But why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nm-main-menu ul.sub-menu").hover(function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass("hovered");
});
```

use $ instead of jQuery and missed double quotes

Comment: Thanks. I need the jQuery for this one though.

Answer (score 0):

Not only you are missing double quote but also wrong put the class name `.nm-main-menu` instead of `.main-menu` .For sure you should test by `console.log` or `alert`

```
jQuery(".main-menu ul.sub-menu").hover(function(){
        console.log("Working"); //alert("Working");
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass("hovered");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the wrong class name. It's actually right, it came from the actual code I woas working on. I just simplified things for the purpose of this post.